# Apply dominated convergence theorem to show differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f,g \in L^p(\mu), 1 < p < \infty$. Show that the function
$$\phi(t)=\int |f+tg|^pd\mu$$ be differentiable at $t=0$ and find $\phi'(0)$.

---

My try, 
$\psi(t)=|f+tg|^p$ is differentiable at $t=0$, if $p>1$. So
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t}=h(x)$$

I also showed 
$$t\in(0,1),\frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t}\leq |f+g|^p-|f|^p$$
$$t\in(-1,0),\frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{-t}\leq |f-g|^p-|f|^p$$
Then I think I need to use dominated convergence theorem to show
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\int\frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t}d\mu=\int h(x)d\mu$$
But what's a suitable dominator? I think I only found an integrable upper bound for the function, not the absolute value of the function.

Comment: Maybe try to use mean value theorem?

Comment: @wisher May you please elaborate it as an answer?

Comment: The @Milly's solution below is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, when $p>1$, the $p$-power function ($x\to x^p$) over positive real numbers is convex. All inequalities below are due to this observation.

Note that:
$$|f|^p-|f-g|^p\leq  |f+g|^p-|f|^p.\tag{1}$$

Moreover, for all $t\in(-1,1)$, $t\not=0$:

$$|f|^p-|f-g|^p\leq\frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t}\leq |f+g|^p-|f|^p.\tag{2}$$

Indeed, for $s\in (0,1)$, $p>1$:

$$ |f+sg|^p = |(1-s)f+s(f+g)|^p \leq (1-s)|f|^p +s|f+g|^p,\tag{3}$$

***and***

$$ |f-sg|^p = |(1-s)f+s(f-g)|^p \leq (1-s)|f|^p +s|f-g|^p.\tag{4}$$

Set $s$ to $t$ when $t$ is positive, and to $-t$ when $t$ is negative, to cover all cases you need.

**Edit1:** For (1), we have:
$$ |h+k|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|h|^p+|k|^p).$$
Indeeed, letting $\theta$ denote the $p$-power function, and using its convexity (and triangle inequality for first step) we have:
$$ |1/2h+1/2k|^p\leq (1/2|h|+1/2|k|)^p=\theta(1/2|h|+1/2|k|)$$ $$\leq 1/2\theta(|h|) +1/2\theta(|k|)=1/2|h|^p+1/2|k|^p.$$
Then we take $h:=f-g$, $k:=f+g$, to obtain (1).

**Edit2:**
Inequality (3) is obtained using the same technique:

$$ |(1-s)f+s(f-g)|^p\leq ((1-s)|f|+s|f-g|)^p=\theta((1-s)|f|+s|f-g|)$$ $$\leq (1-s)\theta(|f|) +s\theta(|f-g|)=(1-s)|f|^p+s|f-g|^p.$$

**Edit3:**

Back to (1), replacing $g$ with $tg$ we get:

$$ |f|^p-|f-tg|^p\leq  |f+tg|^p-|f|^p.$$

Now, replacing $g$ by $-g$ in our right inequality (proven for $t\in (0,1)$) we have:
$$ \frac{|f-tg|^p-|f|^p}{t}\leq |f-g|^p-|f|^p$$
equivalent to
$$ |f|^p - |f-g|^p \leq \frac{|f|^p-|f-tg|^p}{t} $$
which is further 
$$ |f|^p - |f-g|^p \leq \frac{|f|^p-|f-tg|^p}{t} \leq \frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t}, $$
our left inequality for $t\in (0,1)$.

Comment: I have three questions about your answer. 1) If $x^p$ is convex, why $|f+tg|^p$ is convex in $t$? 2) why inequality 1 is true even we don't know whether $f,g>0$ or not? 3) to me, it seems that we only find an upper bound for LHS for inequality 2 when $t\in (0,1)$, why you say inequality 2 holds for $t\in (-1,1)$, that is how do you find the lower bound of LHS when $t\in(0,1)$? May you explain more on above three points? Thanks.

Comment: Oops. I thought that (3) and (4) (or similar) would imply (2). But now I'm confused too. I have to think about it. Sorry. (We shouldn't make any assumptions on $f$ or $g$, otherwise this wouldn't be a good solution.)

Comment: The suggested solution is similar to yours. But it doesn't show how to use (3) (4) to get (2).

Comment: I think we need to go back to (1) and replace $g$ with $tg$.

Comment: Let me know if Edit3 works for you.

Comment: Yeah. And one more question, even if we have $f<g<h$ where $f,h$ are integrable (say the inequality (2)), but we don't know whether $f,h>0$ or not, can we directly apply dominated convergence theorem? I thought we have to get something like $|g|\leq |h|$ for some integrable $h$.

Comment: What we did here works for complex-valued functions $f$ and $g$. The quotient we are interest in is indeed a real-valued function, call it $\alpha$. If we have both bounds for it, the $|\alpha|$ is automatically bounded from above. Also, note that $f$, $|f+g|$, $|f-g|$ don't depend on $t$ at all, and are integrable.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply!

Answer (score 2):

Set

$$F(t) := |f+t \cdot g|^p.$$

Then, by the chain rule,

$$\left| \frac{d}{dt} F(t) \right| = p |f+t \cdot g|^{p-1} \cdot |g| \leq p 2^{p} \big( |f|^{p-1} + |g|^{p-1}\big) \cdot |g| =: h$$

for any $|t| \leq 1$. (Hint for the inequality: Use $|a+b|^{q} \leq 2^q \max\{|a|^q,|b|^q) \leq 2^{q+1} (|a|^q+|b|^q)$ for $q=p-1$.) Consequently, by the mean value theorem,
$$\begin{align*} \left| \frac{|f+tg|^p-|f|^p}{t} \right| &= \left| \frac{F(t)-F(0)}{t} \right|  \leq \sup_{s \in [0,t]} |F'(s)| \leq h \end{align*}$$

for any $ |t|\leq 1$. Finally note that by Hölder's inequality $h$ is integrable. This means that we have found an integrable dominating function.

Comment: For $|f+t \cdot g|^{p-1} \leq 2^{p-1}  \big( |f|^{p-1} + |g|^{p-1}$, what I do is $|f+t \cdot g|^{p-1}\leq (|f|+|g|)^{p-1}\leq (2|f|)^{p-1}\leq 2^{p-1}  \big( |f|^{p-1} + |g|^{p-1}$ if $|g|\leq |f|$. How to use Holder inequality to show that?

Comment: @JohnZHANG If you apply Hölder's inequality to $v:=(a,b)$ and $e:=(1,1)$ for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, then it follows that $$|a \cdot 1 + b \cdot 1|^p \leq 2^{p-1} (|a|^p+|b|^p)$$ for any $p \geq 1$. If we apply this for $p \hat{=}p-1$, then we obtain an estimate of the form I mentioned. (For $p \in (0,1)$ we can use that $|x|^{p-1}$ is subadditive since it is a concave function.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\big||f+tg|^p-|f|^p\big| = p|tg|\cdot|\xi|^{p-1} $, where (for any $x$) $\min\{f+tg,f\}\leq \xi \leq \max \{f+tg,f\}$. Hence (wlog assume $t<1$, since you are really interested in $t\to 0$) $|\xi|\leq |f|+|g|$, i.e.
$$\big||f+tg|^p-|f|^p\big| = p|tg|\cdot|\xi|^{p-1}\leq p t |g|(|f|+|g|)^{p-1}\leq pt|g|\cdot \max \{2, 2^{p-2}\}(|f|^{p-1}+|g|^{p-1})$$
and Holder to control $\int |f|^{p-1}|g|$...